# Filtering by Date in Metabase Dashboard doesn't

Tags: sql, postgresql, business-intelligence, metabase

Unfortunately, I am struggling for hours with filtering by `date` in a native `sql` query. Someone out there with deep metabase experience?

```
select to_date("date", 'YYYYMMDD') AS Date, 
round(sum("price"), 2) AS "Revenue"
from "cdw_transactions"
group by Date
WHERE Date = {{Date}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be rewritten as:

```
select to_date("date", 'YYYYMMDD') AS "Date", 
round(sum("price"), 2) AS "Revenue"
from "cdw_transactions"
where "date" = {{Date}}               -- where before grouping
group by to_date("date", 'YYYYMMDD'); -- matching select
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter *before* the `group by`.  However, there is no actual need for the `group by` because you only want to return one row.

I think something like this:

```
select {{Date}} AS Date, 
       round(sum("price"), 2) AS "Revenue"
from "cdw_transactions"
where to_date("date", 'YYYYMMDD') = {{Date}};
```